# Using the basic laws of exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I have some problems with this question. Please help me. Thanks

> Simplify given expression$$
> a^2 (abc)^{-2} a^3 b^7
> $$

What are exponents of $a$, $b$, and $c$?

I get $3,5,-2$ as exponents of $a,b,c$ respectively. Is it correct?

Comment: That makes no sense at all.

Comment: How about $a=b=c=1$?

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to simplify the expression, and what you mean in your last line is that i simplifies to $a^3b^5c^{-2}$, which is correct.

Comment: Please un-accept my answer(by clicking again on $\checkmark$) I want to take it down as some people here does not seem to like it!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> **Yes**, It is correct!

$$a^2 (abc)^{-2} a^3 b^7=\frac{a^2  a^3 b^7}{(abc)^{2}}=\frac{a^3b^5}{c^2}=a^3b^5c^{-2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you'd like to simplify the problem then
$$ a^2 (abc)^{-2} a^3 b^7= \frac{a^2  a^3 b^7}{(abc)^2}= \frac{a^{2} a^3b^7}{a^2b^2c^2}= \frac{ a^3b^7}{b^2c^2} = \frac{ a^3b^5}{c^2}=a^3b^5c^{-2} $$
Here's a [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for future reference.